# Inserting events from json object to fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

Hello folks I am trying to utilize the fullcalendar to display some holidays I have acquired from a json object.

JSON looks as follows.

```
    var holidayObj = [
            {
                "holidayName" : "Boxing Day",
                "holidayStart" : "May, 26 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST",
                "holidayEnd" : "May, 26 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST"  
            }
            {
                "holidayName" : "Some other Day",
                "holidayStart" : "May, 23 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST",
                "holidayEnd" : "May, 23 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST"  
            }

        ];
```

My JS code to display the events on fullcalendar is as follows.

```
    $.each(holidayObj, function(i, item) {
        holidayNameText = item.holidayName;
        console.log(holidayNameText); //"Boxing Day"
        holidayStart = item.holidayStart; //May, 26 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST
        holidayEnd = item.holidayEnd; //May, 26 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST

        var eventObject = {
                title: holidayNameText,
                start: holidayStart,
                end : holidayEnd,
                allDay:true
            };   
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true);
        console.log(eventObject.start);
    });
```

For some reason the events don't seem to be populating on the calendar. Can anyone help me identify what the cause might may be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma to separate the array elements:

```
var holidayObj = [{
    "holidayName": "Boxing Day",
        "holidayStart": "May, 26 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST",
        "holidayEnd": "May, 26 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST"
}, {
    "holidayName": "Some other Day",
        "holidayStart": "May, 23 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST",
        "holidayEnd": "May, 23 Oct 2014 13:00:00 EST"
}];
```

By fixing it, it works fine (see the events in October).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/EGbHt/